# Proving Boolean Function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Can anyone help me if I am right....!!

**The Question Reads:**

Prove that not every boolean function is equal to a boolean function constructed
by only using ^ and v.

**This is my answer**

1. by the double negation
   eg. ~~p = p
2. by the exclusive or, eg. p XOR q. Thus its 4 properties state that;

   -XOR operation is Commutative . A^B=B^A

   -XOR operation is Associative . (A^B)^C=A^(B^C)

   -XOR ing of same number is zero. A^A=0

   -XOR has zero(0) as the identity element. A^0=A

Answer (score 0):

The operations $(\land, \vee)$ form only monotonic boolean functions. That means they are non-decreasing (with TRUE being greater than FALSE). The NOT operation allows for non-monotonic boolean functions. The XOR function is defined usnig NOT. Commutativity and associativity don't have anything to do with it. The OR operation has identity 0 as well. XORing a TRUE value with itself is a correct way to prove the claim. Double negation is not, as it is just the identity function, which is monotonic.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help..GBU

Comment: Glad I could help!